# how to choose file output path in java

Tags: java

i have this encryption code am developing, the problem is once i choose the file to encrypt and encrypt it, its saved in the default net beans project folder and all encrypted files with similar name. i want to be able to choose the file location and rename the encrypt output, any help will be appreciated.

here is a sample of part of the code

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    file_path.setText(f.getAbsolutePath());
}                                        

private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(file_path.getText());
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("Encrypt.mp4");
        byte k[]="Crot2116MpFr5252".getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(k, "AES");
        Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        enc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(outStream, enc);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read=file.read(buf))!=-1){
            cos.write(buf,0,read);
        }
        file.close();
        outStream.flush();
        cos.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Video file was encrypted Successfully");
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid selection");
    }
}
```

Comment: What about a full path instead of just a file name? Wouldn't something like `new FileOutputStream("Y:\our\chosen\path\to\Encrypt.mp4")` work?

Comment: Sounds like you want a [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) or similar to get the path, then just write the file.

Comment: @deHaar was thinking of that, but the thing is I want to be able to choose the file location instead of using a static file path and also be able to rename the file output name cause apparently everything i encrypt has the same name "Encrypt.somn" and i want to be able to change that

Comment: @MichaelBerry actually the displayed code is just a part, i am using JFileChooser to select the file i wanna encrypt, my problem is being able to choose the output file path as well

Comment: OK, then you might have to rely on some GUI, like @MichaelBerry suggested, maybe choose a directory and provide some text field for the file name.

Comment: @c-root In that case we'll need an [mcve], otherwise we're just guessing on your problem.

Comment: @MichaelBerry alright, lemme edit the code on the post

Comment: @c-root Afraid that's not a [mcve] - it's not complete. (It needs to be self-contained - that's just a method and another block of code somewhere else. We can't take that code and just run it.)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the full path on the `FileOutputStream`:

```
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/file");
```

Here an absolute path is being used (the root path of the File System Manager).
You can also use a relative path to the project without putting the first `/`:

```
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("path/to/file");
```

Like this the file will be saved in `src/main/path/to/file`.